# Algorithm to find water in a matrix after infinite time

Tags: algorithm, matrix, data-structures

A 2-d matrix is given as input which consists of water(W), Grass(G) and Block(B)

Forex: a 4*4 matrix is given

```
W G W G   
B G B G
G G B G
W G G G
```

After every unit of time, water flows in all four directions(if not blocked). Initially suppose the time = 0,

after time = 1 unit, the matrix looks like

```
W W W W    
B G B G   
W G B G      
W W G G
```

Suppose, you have infinite time, how will this matrix look like.
We have to print the time matrix after infinite time for this input matrix.

Output:

```
0 1 0 1
-1 2 -1 2
1 2 -1 3
0 1 2 3
```

Here 0 represents the water was there initially at t=0. And,
1, 2, 3 represents the water will reach there after t=1, 2 and 3 units respectively.

This question is asked in an interview process for SDE-1 profile.

My approach:
Traverse the 2-d array and check for grass, wherever we find the grass, recursively traverse for all the four directions until we find the water or block or boundary. 
Worst-case Time complexity: O(n^4) as we first need to travel the 2-d array and after that, we are recursively calling in every 4 direction.

Is there any way to do better than n^4? Also, where I can practise these kinds of questions for interview perspective.

Comment: You can use a flood fill algorithm.

Comment: Flood fill algorithm will do what I mentioned above. I need to reduce the time complexity of the problem. Am I getting it wrong?

Comment: no, floodfill will take at most *O(n^2), since you simply keep track of items that are filled. It acts a bit like Dijkstra. But with multiple sources, and each vertex has exactly four neighbours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple BFS from multiple sources (that would be your initial water) and find shortest distances. That would take you O(n^2) time.

Make BFS queue, add there every initial water. Set answer for those as 0. Also set answer for all blocks as -1. Then while queue is not empty repeat:

- take node u from the top of the queue
- for each neighbour v (4 sides in this case):

  - if v is block, ignore
  - if v is already visited, ignore
  - set ans[v] as ans[u] + 1, set v as visited and add v to the queue

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Need more clarifications on this

Comment: Shortest distances will take O(n^2) itself. And doing that for all the multiple sources will take O(n^4)

Comment: BFS visits each node once and finds closest distance to it. You have O(n^2) nodes, so it would take O(n^2) time.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Btw, if you want to prepare better for algorithm questions on the interviews I'd suggest trying to solve problems on websites like CodeForces (not necessarily making contests, but tasks from problemset, most of them have also tutorials if you ever get stuck), TopCoder, CodeChief or whatever similar.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I am considering TopCoder and InterviewBit for now.